# Grant_type missing in request

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to get token access (protocol oauth2) to dynamics 365.

That's the code that build and execute the http post request:

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder()
                    .setScheme("https")
                    .setHost("login.microsoftonline.com")
                    .setPath("/"+PropertyUtils.getInstance().getProperty("AD_TENANT_ID")+"/oauth2/token")
                    .setParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials")
                    .setParameter("client_id", PropertyUtils.getInstance().getProperty("CLIENT_ID"))
                    .setParameter("resource", PropertyUtils.getInstance().getProperty("RESOURCE"))
                    .setParameter("client_secret", PropertyUtils.getInstance().getProperty("CLIENT_SECRET"))
                    .build();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

the response json is:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r ...
```

why response tell me that grant_type is missing when it's in the request as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to perform the request putting those parameters in the URI as query parameters. Although those parameters needs to be put in the body of the request as form url encoded.

```
{"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
```

Comment: You can check https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-post-http-request#basic-post
as an example for Posting with HttpClient